# Symfony Doctrine: orderBy JSONb field?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, sql-order-by, jsonb, dql

Is there a way to order by specific jsonb field in doctrine?

Table example:

| id | person_data | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `{'name': 'John Smith', 'number': 13}` | 10000 |
| 2 | `{'name': 'John Doe', 'number': 192}` | 11000 |
| 2 | `{'name': 'Don John', 'number': 87}` | 12000 |

How to order by `person_data->>'name'`?

PostgreSQL style code not working.
`->addOrderBy("person_data->>'name'")`

Throws error: `Error: Expected Literal, got '>'`

Answer (score 0):

I have now found a solution to this problem. There is exists a [third-party library](https://github.com/ScientaNL/DoctrineJsonFunctions) that provides a set of JSON functions from PostgreSQL for Doctrine. Among the supported JSON functions for PostgreSQL is also JsonGet.

To make things work, install first the library

`composer require scienta/doctrine-json-functions`

By configuring this Doctrine DQL function for the entity manager:

```yaml
orm:
    entity_managers:
        default:
            dql:
                string_functions:
                    JSON_GET: Scienta\DoctrineJsonFunctions\Query\AST\Functions\Postgresql\JsonGet
```

The following `orderBy`` statement can be written with the Doctrine QueryBuilder:

```php
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
// ...
$qb->orderBy("JSON_GET(YourAlias.YourField, 'PropertyOfTheJson')");
```

The QueryBuilder translates this statement as follows for PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable ORDER BY yourfield->'PropertyOfTheJson'
```

This worked for me